# Updating MandrillTransport-CakePHP to be 2.4 compatible

Tags: php, cakephp, mandrill

I'm trying to use the plugin MandrillTransport-CakePHP ( https://github.com/khanlou/MandrillTransport-CakePHP/blob/master/MandrillTransport.php ) in my  application, but I'm receiving errors when sending a message.

My send code:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('mandrill');
    $Email->viewVars(array(
        'fname' => $this->User->field('fname'),
    ));
$Email->template('welcome')
    ->from(array('support@domain.com' => 'MySite'))
    ->sender(array('support@domain.com' => 'MySite'))
    ->to($this->User->field('email'))
    ->subject('Welcome to MySite, ' . $this->User->field('fname'))
    ->send());
```

When sending the message I get the errors:

> Notice (8): Undefined property: CakeEmail::$template [APP/Lib/Network/Email/MandrillTransport.php, line 97]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined property: CakeEmail::$viewVars [APP/Lib/Network/Email/MandrillTransport.php, line 105]

I tried changing the lines to $this->_cakeEmail->_template but then I get errors about accessing a protected variable.

Can someone who's more experience with the changes in CakeEmail between 2.0 and 2.4 assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the corresponding methods, i.e. `template()` and `viewVars()`. `viewVars()` simply returns the value of the `_viewVars` property whereas `template()` returns an array and you have to use `template()['template']` to get the value of the `_template` property.

Comment: It turns out the original plugin was using mandrill templates as opposed to CakeEmail templates so I've removed those parts. What I now need to access is CakeEmail-> [_textMessage:protected] but I can't get past "Cannot access protected property CakeEmail::$_textMessage"

Comment: I got it; I needed to call CakeEmail->message(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for future searchers (like me) you might consider an alternative plugin that appears to be more actively maintained: https://github.com/a2design-company/Mandrill-CakePHP-plugin

I haven't used either yet, but they appear to do basically the same thing.